# Bounded class comprehension axiom with a modal operator

Tags: set-theory, foundations, modal-logic

I'm mechanizing set theory (I've been working off IZF.) NBG (Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory) caught my attention because (in theory) it is finitely axiomizable.

But the class comprehension principle seems a bit awkward. I was playing with a different approach of bounding formula over sets with something like modal logic or [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#fiction)?

Your class comprehension principle becomes something like

$$ \vdash \forall x. x \in \{ y \mid P(y)\} \rightarrow \mathop{\text{M}} x $$
$$ \vdash \forall x. x \in \{ y \mid P(y)\} \rightarrow \Diamond P(x)$$

$$ \vdash \forall x. \mathop{\text{M}} x \rightarrow \Box P(x) \rightarrow x \in \{ y \mid P(y)\} $$

You add two "comprehension modalities" with rules for quantifiers like

$$ \Diamond (\forall x. P(x)) \vdash \forall x. \mathop{\text{M}} x \rightarrow  \Diamond P(x)  $$
$$ \Diamond (\exists x. P(x)) \vdash \exists x. \mathop{\text{M}} x \wedge \Diamond P(x)  $$

$$ (\forall x. \mathop{\text{M}} x \rightarrow \Box P(x) ) \vdash \Box (\forall x. P(x)) $$
$$(\exists x. \mathop{\text{M}} x \wedge \Box P(x) ) \vdash  \Box (\exists x. P(x) ) $$

And I **think** you want axioms

$$ \vdash \forall x y. \Diamond (x \in y) \rightarrow x \in y$$
$$ \vdash \forall x y. x \in y \rightarrow \Box (x \in y) $$

I'm most familiar with monadic modalities. I'm not really sure what works the best here.

$$ P\vdash \Diamond P$$

$$\frac{P \vdash \Diamond Q}{\Diamond P\vdash \Diamond Q}$$

$$ \frac{\top \vdash P}{\top \vdash \Box P}$$

$$ \Box P \vdash P$$

$$\Box (P \rightarrow Q) \vdash \Box P\rightarrow \Box Q$$

You would stick most axioms in the comprehension modality.

$$ \vdash \Diamond (\forall x. x \notin \emptyset)$$
$$ \vdash \Diamond (\forall x y z. z \in \{x, y\} \iff z = x \vee z = y) $$

And so on.

Something like this **seems** like it should work for me. But I'm not familiar with formal set theory foundations.

Comment: "(in theory) it is finitely axiomizable" In what sense is this "in theory?" We have an explicit finite axiomatization. Also, what exactly is your modality supposed to be doing here?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I just meant I'm unlikely to implement coding that way in a mechanization. I'm trying to restrict comprehension formulas to only quantify over sets. Just with a modal operator instead of an explicit subset type or something.